# Highlight some dates in react calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar

hello i have this calendar in my project,
i want to highlight some date to mark that they are already used.
can you tell me how to do that please ?

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';

export default function Test() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date.toDateString());
  const dateToMark = [
    '3',
    '10',
    '20',
  ];

  return(
    <div>
      <p>{date}</p>
      <Calendar onChange={setDate} value={date}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

thanks by advance and have a good code day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';

export default function Test() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState([
    '3',
    '10',
    '20',
  ]);

  return(
    <div>
      <p>{date}</p>
      <Calendar onChange={setDate} value={date}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

By passing date like initial value of usestate variable.